# Spring Security, main context-root in ear

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Hi I have ear with many war

```
EAR
 |_WAR1 context-root/ldap
 |_WAR2 context-root/primefaces
 ...
```

Use spring security in `WAR1` I can use login only in  `context-root/ldap` in `context-root/primefaces` Status 404
I find many solution but with application.xml, in my project spring is configure without xml only annotation.
Try use [CAS Authentication](http://www.objectpartners.com/2014/05/20/configuring-spring-security-cas-providers-with-java-config/) but doasn't work.

Set similar context I wont use only localhost:8080/context-root like ticket doasn't work again

```
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>pl.luppo.war</groupId>
                        <artifactId>WarTest</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/context-root/primefaces</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>pl.jar.test</groupId>
                        <artifactId>WarSOAPTest</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/context-root/soap</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>pl.luppo.war.ldap</groupId>
                        <artifactId>WarLDAPOLD</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/context-root/ldap</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
```

Next wont change [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-stack)

```
 @Bean
 public SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
 securityContextPersistenceFilter() {
 HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository = new
 HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
 securityContextRepository.setAllowSessionCreation(false);
 securityContextRepository.setSpringSecurityContextKey("/context-root/");
```

Try `"/context-root" or "context-root"` nothoing

Please help configure some Single Sign On without applicationContext.xml or set one main Context-Root.
I search similar problem but each solutions use applicationContext.xml. I can't change xml solution to annotation.

Whole project (I know i have duplicate *.xhtml in WAR1 and WAR2 and many commented LOC because I try everything and I don't remove that because I wont show whole my project and my attempts )
`http://www.speedyshare.com/FtmW2/PomTest`

Thanks for help

Comment: I use Jboss SSO but doasn't work [JBOSS SSO](https://developer.jboss.org/message/862908)